# Apache NiFi closes immediately with error, org.apache.nifi.StdErr Failed to start web server

Tags: apache-nifi

I have recently installed NiFi, and it was working fine for few days. But suddenly today when i try to open it using `run-nifi.bat`, the NiFi window is getting closed in few seconds stating the below error:

```
    2019-04-11 23:07:40,146 WARN [NiFi Bootstrap Command Listener] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read status file C:\Users\DOWNLO~1\NIFI-1~1.1-B\NIFI-1~1.1\bin\..\run\nifi.status; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
    2019-04-11 23:07:40,149 INFO [NiFi Bootstrap Command Listener] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Apache NiFi now running and listening for Bootstrap requests on port 54149
    2019-04-11 23:08:00,352 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr Failed to start web server: Must configure HTTP or HTTPS connector
    2019-04-11 23:08:00,352 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr Shutting down...
    2019-04-11 23:08:00,419 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi NiFi never started. Will not restart NiFi
```

I do looked out for the `org.apache.nifi.StdErr Failed to start web server: Must configure HTTP or HTTPS connector` error, but unfortunately I cant find a similar one. I'm sure that no settings or properties has been changed since installation. Any suggestion guys?

Comment: Is there a further stacktrace below that? What does your `nifi.properties` look like?

Comment: No @Andy..it ends right there..And I haven't modified any of the properties. Its the default one..

Comment: Thanks for ur response @Andy! I downloaded NiFi again and it seems working fine now..But I'm not sure why it failed before..I wont terminate the NiFi process(`run-nifi.bat`) by EOD, is that a problem?

Comment: That's odd. where did you install/download nifi from the first time? I recommend getting the latest version from https://nifi.apache.org and verifying the checksums after download. What version of Java do you have installed? NiFi currently requires Java 8. To answer your last question, long running nifi processes expected and not a problem, although you may want to start it as a background process.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error.

You need to check `nifi-app.log` file to get more details on this type of error.

Here’s what I did: Remove the port information from `nifi.properties` for HTTPS and only keep the setting for HTTP. Then restart nifi again.

Answer (score 0):

Keep one property enable like https or http. in my case https:127.0.0.1:8443/nifi/

it works fine me.